Qt Connections issue
So there is a View class.
It has a signal " void authstatuschanged(int hr, QString status, int modelno);".
There are two QML files : LoginPanel.qml and MainScreen.qml.
In both the qml files there were signal handlers.
The code for LoginPanel.qml signal handler is this :
 Connections
  {
   
 target: viewobject
    onAuthstatuschanged:
    {

   }
 }


The code for MainScreen.qml signal handler is this:
 Connections
  {
   
 target:viewobject
 onAuthstatuschanged:
    {

}
 }


The code were the signal is emitted is this :
 void View::onauthstatuschanged(int hr, QString status, int modelno)
{
  
 emit authstatuschanged(hr, status , modelno);
 }

The problem started coming when I migrated QT from QT 5.7 to QT 5.14.
In QT 5.7 whenever the signal "authstatuschanged" was getting emitted
the signal handler of MainScreen.qml was getting called
and as soon as the execution of the signal handler was finished,
the signal handler of  LoginPanel.qml was getting called.
In QT 5.14 this never happens.
In Qt 5.14, when  the signal "authstatuschanged" was getting emitted
the signal handler of MainScreen.qml was getting called
but after that the signal handler of LoginPanel.qml did not get called.
How to fix this ?
